# Não estou conseguindo rodar minha aplicação wicket

Tags: wicket

GOstaira de saber como resolver este problema, para adquirir mais conhecimentos estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wicket + Spring integration example</h1>
    <label wicket:id="msg"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Java:

```
package br.com.ordem.servico.servicosautomotivos;

import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;


public class SimplePage extends WebPage{

    @SpringBean
    private HelloService helloService;

    public SimplePage(PageParameters parameters) {
        Label label = new Label("msg", new Model<String>(helloService.getHelloWorldMsg()));
        this.add(label);
    }
}

    package br.com.ordem.servico.servicosautomotivos;

import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication{

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return SimplePage.class;
    }

}
```

> Unexpected RuntimeException
>
> WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public br.com.ordem.servico.servicosautomotivos.SimplePage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument
>
> Root cause:
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at br.com.ordem.servico.servicosautomotivos.SimplePage.(SimplePage.java:16)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Complete stack:
>
> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public br.com.ordem.servico.servicosautomotivos.SimplePage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
>        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
>
> display page view

Comment: Copia o log de erro gerado e posta e formato e de texto e não de imagem por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a classe SimplePage necessita de um construtor padrão, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
public class HelloWorldApplication extends WebApplication {
    public HelloWorldApplication() {
    }
    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#getHomePage()
     */
    @Override
    public Class getHomePage() {
        return HelloWorld.class;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld extends WebPage {
    public HelloWorld() {
        add(new Label("message", "Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

[Exemplo de Hello World no Wicket](https://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/helloworld.html)

Comment: continuo com o mesmo problema!

Comment: O seu Label  tem get e set?

Comment: user5515 estou usando o label do wicket, acredito que tenha sim!

Comment: O que tem no HelloService? Essa Label poderia ser adicionada na tela  assim:  add(new Label("msg", "Hello World!"));

Answer (score 0):

O problema que você está tendo é java.lang.NullPointerException na linha 16, que eu tenho quase certeza que é causado por causa da injeção de dependencia.

```
  @SpringBean
  private HelloService helloService;
```

Esse seu serviço provavelmente está retornando null e isso está ocasionando o null pointer.

Para saber sobre o que está causando o problema na injeção de dependência é necessário que você passe informações sobre o seu HelloService.